# Passing apex:inputField user entry as parameter into Command Link

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, pagereference

I am getting the nickname from an inputField and updating a list of strings and displaying the list of strings on a table. The outputField displays the newly entered value, but the controller variable seems to store the previous value even when I use the same `{!Object.nickName}` as the value attribute in both cases.

Test:

1) when I enter "1":
 Output box: 1,
 List retrieved from controller: (nothing)

2) Enter "2":
 Output box: 2,
 List retrieved from controller: 1

What is the issue here? Why is the same `{!Object.nickName}` retrieving two different values when it is an outputField vs controller variable(system debug/pageblocktable)

Vf Page:

```
<script>
    function checkName() {
        updateNicknameList( $('input[id$=Name]').val());
        }     
    }
</script>

<apex:form >

    <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateNicknameList" action="{!updateNicknameList}" immediate="true" rerender="nicknameDisplay">
        <apex:param name="Name" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>        
    <apex:inputField id="Name" value="{!Object.nickName}" onblur="checkName()"/>    
    <apex:outputField value="{!Object.nickName}"/>
    <apex:commandLink value="Add nickname" action="{!processLinkClick}">
        <apex:param name="nickName" value="{!Object.nickName}" assignTo="{!nickName}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
    <Code Displaying the nicknames as a table>
</apex:form >
```

Controller:

```
//Defining standard controllers

//Constructor initializes data members

public void updateNicknameList() {
        String Name = '';
        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name') != null) {
            Name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name');
            this.Object.nickName = Name;
            this.nickNameList.add(Name);
        }
public PageReference processLinkClick() {
        this.nickNames.add(nickName);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a debug statement and check what your controller receives.

in addition see this Post in the DeveloperForce forum
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/How-do-I-pass-value-of-apex-inputField-to-Custom-Controller/td-p/532905

Comment: Yes I was checking values with debug statements, the issue seems to be with the way I was passing the input field in the script: updateNicknameList( $('input[id$=Name]').val());

Answer (score 0):

I was checking values with debug statements and alerts, the issue seems to be with the way I was passing the input field in the script:

```
updateNicknameList( $('input[id$=Name]').val());
<apex:inputField id="Name" value="{!Object.nickName}" onblur="checkName()"/>
```

When I tried the method used in the above link from Seb__Wagner, the issue is resolved:

```
updateNicknameList( document.getElementById(name).value );
<apex:inputField id="check" value="{!Object.nickName}" onchange="checkName('{!$Component.check}');"/>
```

Thanks Seb__Wagner, this issue had been eating my head yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using ActionFunction to post Object.nickName to controller, then in controller set the Object.nickName again.  As you're using a bind variable for inputField, the controller will automatically update with a new value once you click on your commandLink.

Essentially your page will function with the following page code (with no additional javascript):

```
<apex:inputField id="Name" value="{!Object.nickName}" />    
<apex:outputField value="{!Object.nickName}"/>
<apex:commandLink value="Add nickname" action="{!processLinkClick}" reRender="nicknameTable" />
<Code Displaying the nicknames as a table>
```

and controller:

public PageReference processLinkClick() {

```
    this.nickNames.add(this.object.nickName);
    return null;
}
```